# do something, when scrolling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

On my page I append a div with class container to `#grid` (a div).

Now i wish to "do something" when I scroll this container div.

I've tried this code, but it didn't work:

```
$('.container').scroll(function(){
  //do something
});
```

and

```
$('.container').live('scroll',function(){
  //do something
});
```

Comment: you want to put "do something" on screen? If so you should at least alert it or something like that...

Answer (score 3):

Try this code....

```
$('#grid div.container').unbind('scroll');
$('#grid div.container').bind('scroll', function(e) {
//Do something 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Normally you need to scroll on either the window, or some sort of div/etc that has `overflow:scroll`, aka, has a scrollbar itself (like an iFrame for example). It seems like you're applying it randomly to a class of things. Try appending it to the window.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    alert("we're scrolling");
});
```

[jsFiddle DEMO w/ a div #id](http://jsfiddle.net/vuJq9/)